# Упорядочивание по двум элементам?

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть база такого вида
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
хочу привести запрос к виду

```
1 предприятие 1 товар 
1 предприятие 2 товар
2 предприятие 1 товар
```

таким запросом я выбираю и сортирую все предприятия

```
select factory.id,
  factory.name
FROM 
  a_element element,
  t_factory factory,
  a_analiz_data data,
  a_analiz_create analiz
where
  data.value::int = factory.id
  and data.analiz_id = analiz.id
  and data.elem_id = element.id
  and 't_factory' = element.name
  order by factory.name
```

но дело в том что в поле data.value лежит ид из таблицы factory.
а в name.element - имя таблицы.
сюда же мне нужно добавить выборку из таблицы t_ware. она подобным с factory образом в data.value хранит ид из таблицы ware, а в таблице element.name имя таблицы

выбор из t_ware

```
SELECT 
  id,
  name  
FROM 
  t_ware
```

---

### update ответ

нужно было сделать объединяющий запрос

```
SELECT 
distinct 
fact_id, ware_id //то что хотел получить - пару предприятие+товар
FROM
  a_analiz_create analiz, 
 (SELECT 
   factory.id as fact_id,
  factory.name as fact_name,
    factory.nickname,
   factory.type,
   factory.gal_id,
   factory.consumer,
   factory.enabled,
   factory.comment,
   data.analiz_id
 FROM 
   a_element element,
   t_factory factory,
   a_analiz_data data
 where
   data.value::int = factory.id
   and data.elem_id = element.id
   and 't_factory' = element.name
  ) factory,  //таким образом выдергиваю из factory предприятие
 (SELECT 
   ware.id as ware_id,
   ware.name,
   ware.gal_id,
   ware.parent_id,
   ware.extname,
   ware.gost,
   ware.comment,
   ware.enabled,
   data.analiz_id
 FROM 
   a_element element,
   t_ware  ware,
   a_analiz_data data
 where
   data.value::int = ware.id
   and data.elem_id = element.id
   and 't_ware' = element.name
) ware  //тут получаю данные о товаре
where
  analiz.id = factory.analiz_id
  and analiz.id = ware.analiz_id
  and to_char(analiz.f_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM') //за текущий месяц
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно из вопроса. Таблицы одни, в запросе другие. Приведите скрипты создания таблиц и примерные данные, чтобы мы могли воспроизвести запросы и помочь...

Comment: Смысл замораживать вопрос как непонятный, когда уже есть принятый ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `order by` можно указывать несколько параметров через запятую.